# project can't be set as Class Library in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I just started using VS and I created a C# project with the `Class Library (.NET Standard)` template. Yet in the project property page the output type is always `Windows Application`. Even if I change it to `Class Library` and save, the setting will always get automatically restored back to `Windows Application` when I reopen the project property page. However, when I built the project, VS did compile it to a .dll file.
Could this be a bug in VS (since I'm using 2017 RC)? Or am I misunderstanding something here?

Comment: That does seem like unexpected behavior.

Comment: @EJoshuaS Can you elaborate?

Comment: I'm speculating a little here but that does sound like it could be a legitimate bug.

Comment: There's actually another bug. When I tried to change the `Assembly Information` of my project, VS simply crashed...every time.

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue. Did you find any solutions?

Comment: @TommyJakobsen I reported this as a bug to the VS team, and they labeled it as "triaged". No update after that. If you want to target .NET Standard you can try creating a .NET Core class library that targets it for now (this is what I did), and move to a .NET Standard class library when VS 2017 is officially released.

Comment: Update (though might be a little bit late): on 2017-01-06, my report is labeled as `Fixed - Pending Release`. Since it is now 2017-02-19, this bug might already be fixed (same goes to the assembly information crash bug mentioned above).